# Swift: Is there a way to init array entries from consecutive swift files?

Tags: swift

I can't find a good way to do that:

My app needs to load a bunch of levels into an array on startup like this:

```
import Foundation


var levels: [Level] = []

func assignLevels() {

    levels.append(Level(goodAnswers: ["Churchill", "Winston Churchill"], otherAnswers: [:]))
    levels.append(Level(goodAnswers: ["Mount Everest"], otherAnswers: [:]))
    levels.append(Level(goodAnswers: ["forest", "woods"], otherAnswers: [:]))
   //... etc...
}
```

.. so that I can then easily look them up by index in the array. It works perfectly fine, but I was wondering if there is a way to do each `append` in a separate swift file and somehow iterate through all of them on startup?

Example:

level1.swift:

```
levels.append(Level(goodAnswers: ["Churchill", "Winston Churchill"], otherAnswers: [:]))
```

level2.swift:

```
levels.append(Level(goodAnswers: ["Mount Everest"], otherAnswers: [:]))
```

level3.swift:

```
levels.append(Level(goodAnswers: ["forest", "woods"], otherAnswers: [:]))
```

However, expressions are not allowed at the top level so not sure what would be the best way to have initial values for the array entries in separate files.
I was experimenting with turning each question into a function (`func level001() -> Level` `func level002() -> Level`etc) and then running all of them by iterating via function name, but this seems like an overkill and not very elegant at that.

It's not strictly necessary but would be significantly more convenient to have nicely separated files rather than one very long one.

Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: "if there is a way to do each append in a separate swift file" (1) Why is this advantageous for you? What's the point of doing it that way? (2) Why do this in separate lines of code at all? Why not just load a separate plist file that has all the info and create the whole array in _one_ line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Since a Level is presumably a lightweight object, it would be simplest to load all the Levels at once from a file in the app bundle. Here's an example file (I've used plist format):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>GoodAnswers</key>
        <array>
            <string>Winston Churchill</string>
            <string>Churchill</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>GoodAnswers</key>
        <array>
            <string>Mount Everest</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>GoodAnswers</key>
        <array>
            <string>forest</string>
            <string>woods</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I include that file in my bundle as *Levels.plist*. And I have declared a Level type like this (yours would be more complicated, of course, but the idea is the same):

```
struct Level {
    let goodAnswers : [String]
    let otherAnswers : [String : String]
    init?(dict:[String:Any]) {
        if let goodAnswers = dict["GoodAnswers"] as? [String] {
            self.goodAnswers = goodAnswers
            self.otherAnswers = [:]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now creating the Levels array at launch is trivial:

```
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Levels", withExtension: "plist")!)
let levels = (try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! Array<[String:Any]>)
    .map(Level.init(dict:))
    .compactMap{$0}
```

The result is your array of Levels:

```
[Level(goodAnswers: ["Winston Churchill", "Churchill"], otherAnswers: [:]),
 Level(goodAnswers: ["Mount Everest"], otherAnswers: [:]),
 Level(goodAnswers: ["forest", "woods"], otherAnswers: [:])]
```

The point is that the plist file *Levels.plist* can be as long as you like, with as many levels as you like, but the *code* at launch does not grow at all. This is super efficient and much better than hard coding the level data into the *code* of the app itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The level object is indeed rather lightweight, however I'm looking for something a bit different here. The most important part is to have the levels in separate files - I can already put them into one long file. The reason being, there will be quite a number of them and it will be easier to maintain by just opening, say "level092" file rather than looking it up in a sizeable "levels" file. Hence just wondering how would it be accomplished.